# CSS - background position - in cases of a normal picture and a sprite

Tags: css

so in CSS, i gather the use of background position can be used to control where you want to position your picture (a single image.)

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

will position the image from the top left corner.

However, I get confused when the concept of sprite was introduced to me, as i thought when you change the value of x and y px, you are just moving the image to a different area on the website, instead of choosing which image inside the sprite that you want to use. say we have a sprite,shouldn't the difference between

```
 background-position: 0px 0px;
```

and

```
 background-position: 30px 30px;
```

be the same icon is moved 30 px right and 30 px down?

However, in other tutorials, the position of the image does not change. Instead they can use background-position to choose the image inside the sprite based on the coordinates of the sprite.

I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

so sprite has more than one image joined together. .. so there is only one image(large one comprising of smaller ones).

now suppose you use that sprite as background of a div.

now to clarify your doubt .. assume div is window through which you can see only certain part of image ..
so in sprite we first show only certain part of image and how do we do that?

by positioning that part of sprite behind the window (ie div) by giving initial background position value

now when you change background position that large sprite image moves (remember there is only one large image composed of small images) .. so when it moves some other part of sprite is visible through window (ie background image of div changes)

and that is how new image is visible through div...

so understand it this way

its not a new image necessarily which comes but some other portion of sprite image, which you see when background position changes

have a look if this helps https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/